# ESP8266 & Javascript AES

Tags: javascript, aes, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I have this encrypted AES128 CBC zero padding :

```
o9MfCaefrs8pM8zQqyQ2mQ==
key = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
iv = 0000000000000000
```

I am looking for decryption code to let esp8266 decrypt it any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As a Knowledge Seeker, did you google with "encrypt & decrypt a string arduino" or "encrypt & decrypt a string javascript" to find out?